# Why does including web_tester.php in SimpleTest make tests 1/2 complete

Tags: php, simpletest

I was trying to follow the examples on the SimpleTest website, and whenever I include web_tester.php, the status bar changes from 1/1 complete to 1/2 complete.  Why is this?

For example, I tried creating one of the example test cases, which has the following code:

```
<?php
    require_once('simpletest/autorun.php');
    require_once('simpletest/web_tester.php');

    class TestOfLastcraft extends WebTestCase {

        function testHomepage() {
            $this->assertTrue($this->get('http://www.lastcraft.com/'));
        }
    }
?>
```

When I view this file in the browser, the green status bar shows 1/2 tests complete.  What/where is this other test that it is trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

You should include below codes in your code, this line could pretend Simpletest to count WebTestCase as a TestCase.

```
SimpleTest::ignore( 'WebTestCase' );
```